# Detect uninstalled app : How to send an Fcm request to many devices to know with one are unregistered from Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**I want to detect all users who uninstall my app**. For this every night I send an FCM data message to all my users and catch the api error message like `NotRegistered` or `InvalidRegistration/InvalidApnsCredential`. The problem is that with more than 100.000 users this is an heavy task to do every days!

Is their a way to send in "bulk" all my data messages and know with users are not registered anymore?

Comment: Device registration tokens can change over time.  A changed token becomes invalid.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the user uninstalled the app, it just means that they might have new token.  Also consider that the user's device might be shut off or lacking connectivity, and can't respond to a message.  So I don't think FCM is the right tool for this job.  You're probably better off looking for users that just haven't launched the app after some amount of time.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I know about changed token. when the app detect a change in the token it's inform my server with the new token so that ok :) looking for user that just haven't launch my app for some amount of time is not good solution, because I will never know when they uninstall my app

Comment: If the user shuts off their device or just discards it and buys a new one, your app will not be able to report a changed token, and you will have no way of knowing if that was actually the case.

Comment: @DougStevenson that ok, if i can detect with accuracy of 1 day 99% of uninstall and if i have 1% of error :) I think user who shut off definitively their device is quite rare!

Comment: My opinion is that you're just going to have problems with this, but suit yourself. I don't think there is any shortcut for sending messages to individual devices either.

Comment: @DougStevenson I agree with you, but if you have a better option to detect when user exactly uninstall the app I took it :)

Comment: I personally think and end user has the right to uninstall an app privately without the app developer monitoring that behavior. I'd make an exception for corporate devices that need to be controlled securely, but it sounds like that is not your situation.

Comment: @DougStevenson : I don't care to know with user uninstall the app, but I need to have statistic to know if the app is wrong, if this advertisement is wrong, etc. no need to have info on a particular user

Comment: Any news? facing the same issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483884/fcm-detect-app-uninstall-on-ios-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications