# FCM detect app uninstall on IOS (firebase cloud messaging push notifications)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm detecting app uninstalls using FCM. I'm sending silent notifications to users, if I'm getting `NotRegistered` response, I know that the app is uninstalled.

However, on IOS I'm always getting `success` responses, even on uninstalled apps. FCM [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) says that `NotRegistered` is provided:

> If the client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNs Feedback Service reported the APNs token as invalid.

Why on IOS app uninstall the `APNs Feedback Service` does not update the token status to `invalid`? Why am I getting `success` while the app is uninstalled?

On Android everything is just fine, I'm getting `NotRegistered` response as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firebase analytics? If you are, it automatically detects installs and uninstalls
Also, Play Store and AppStore, both have tools to monitor installs and uninstall.
You don't need to manually build such a system as it will only waste server usage.

Comment: Hey @MaddyB welcome to the StackOverflow community! Yes I'm using firebase analytics but `app_remove` events are sent only from Android devices (and most of the time they are not sent at all).

Comment: Thank you @genericUser !! So we have to do some iOS specific configuration to get Firebase analytics running properly on it. I don't remember it exactly, since I've worked with iOS only once and it has been a while. I'll look into that project and get back to you. Maybe use AppStore analytics for the time being